# Run c# code on client side or make a web session interactive?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis-6, windows-server-2008

I'm making an application on c# for signing PDFs. Its works perfectly on my visual studio web project, but when I publish it on my test server it throws me this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY5Sb.png)

In this case I'm trying to execute the code that sign a pdf on the server and the error occurs specifically on the line:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms.ComputeSignature()
```

It is supposed to throws a window on your desktop asking for your certificate (reading a smart Card) and then asking for your PIN just like this
[Windows Security Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeYuw.png) but I have the hunch that it's not possible because Its implies that the server have to have the possibility to interact with the client's desktop

Ok, now that I've explained all the enviroment that I'm facing, here are the solutions I've tried until now:

1) Trying to correct the Server Error above: I went in the server to IIS>application Pool>MyPage>Advanced Settings>Process Model>Load User Profile and selected True instead of False (*Didn't Work*)

2) Still trying to correct the Server Error I Went to Computer Management>Services and Application>Services and turned on the service "Interactive Service Detection" (*Still not working and doesn't work even if I do the same on the client computer*)

3)Finally, I guess that it's not possible to run the code on the server because the Error line above is a native calling of Windows Security so I thought: what if I try to run the code right from the client?. Like a c# applet equivalent or something, well... there are two ways for do that: ActiveX (old technology) and Silverlight (newer). The thing is that I just can't make a simple Silverlight program start on chrome, it does on firefox and IE but if doesn't work on chrome is a totally waste so my last option is to make it run with an ActiveX, and there is almost none useful information in the internet about that

If someone can tell me what to do, either to correct the error or to make my program run from the client side, I would be so grateful

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for functionality modern browsers don't support, because they violate the sandboxing principles of the browser (code in the browser shouldn't be able to interact with the user's system outside of carefully proscribed paths). Is there any reason you couldn't just implement a modal in js?

Comment: Well I can't because I don't know what does the method "computeSignature()" does and the internal code is invisible to me because is part of a cryptographic security library. If I could just do a modal in JS, I would have done already (*please re-read the question, I've just edit it*)

Comment: Hi, you never put images in your question when referring to errors. Use the code snippet. Is an advice or someone will downvote your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call the system's api from a Web client as this would break the sandbox. If you must use that system call, create a wrapper on the server that will handle the popup, although this would be a very "hacky" solution. You should really be asking why I am trying to use a Web client interface if I must use said native system call.